# How to check if nested params exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I try to create search with ransack.
To do this, I need to check if nested parameters exist.

I get next params:

```
 Parameters: {"q"=>{"category_id"=>"2", "name_cont"=>"test"}
```

How can I check if I get params [:category_id] or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Ruby >= 2.3.0, you can make use of [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
params.dig(:q, :category_id)
```